# Objective-C How to Determine when Messages App of Apple Sends a sms message

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I reference the Messages app of apple to my app so I can increment x every time it sends a sms message.

I'm not trying to create an app that sends sms message. It's just a view with a large label that shows a number of how many times I've sent a message from Messages app.

Comment: It's not possible using non-private APIs, and possibly not without root access (Jailbreak).

Comment: You can´t get this information on a non-jailbroken phone. This is private information to the user and should be hidden.

Comment: Oh I see, I was planning on making that app since I only have 100 text messages per month and take track of it. It's really sad that I cannot make it.

Comment: Perhaps you could contact your operator and try to get instructions on how to get your stats, they might have an API for that. Doing it the way you planned is not really a good solution since the messages can be sent with other devices or with the same device and another SIM card.

Comment: Sadly they don't provide stats that's why I'm finding a better solution other than making notes in my phone. Do you think there's a better solution to my problem?